# canno't send from plesk webmail to Gmail " a simple mail"

Tags: gmail, plesk, webmail

after i change my hostname in plesk " there was a IP adress but now i cant change hostname to ip" i can't send email to gmail. on outlook works propperly and plus on info@mydomain.com i cant send to info@myclientdomain.com email but on gmail i can't pls help me i'm getting this error

```
This is the mail system at host server1.mydomain.ge.
I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.

 If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

               The mail system

 <astronaut.georgia@gmail.com>: host
gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400c:c08::1a] said: 550-5.7.1
[2a01:4f8:c2c:fe73::1] Our system has detected that this message does
550-5.7.1 not meet IPv6 sending guidelines regarding PTR records and
550-5.7.1 authentication. Please review 550-5.7.1
https://support.google.com/mail/?p=IPv6AuthError for more information 550
5.7.1 . k2si2790691wrg.299 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command)
Reporting-MTA: dns; mydomain.com
  X-Postfix-Queue-ID: 03B9E6257E
  X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; info@mydomain.com
  Arrival-Date: Thu,  5 Nov 2020 20:26:02 +0100 (CET)

  Final-Recipient: rfc822; astronaut.georgia@gmail.com
  Original-Recipient: rfc822;astronaut.georgia@gmail.com
 Action: failed
 Status: 5.7.1
 Remote-MTA: dns; gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
 Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-5.7.1 [2a01:4f8:c2c:fe73::1] Our system has detected
that this message does 550-5.7.1 not meet IPv6 sending guidelines regarding
PTR records and 550-5.7.1 authentication. Please review 550-5.7.1
https://support.google.com/mail/?p=IPv6AuthError for more information 550
5.7.1 . k2si2790691wrg.299 - gsmtp
 გამგზავნი  info@mydomain.com
 ვის    astronaut.georgia@gmail.com
 თარიღი დღეს 23:26
 qqq
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply the solution from this KB article - https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213936285-Unable-to-send-an-email-to-Gmail-from-a-Plesk-server-Our-system-has-detected-that-this-message-does-not-meet-IPv6-sending-guidelines-regarding-PTR-records